# "Have been with for" vs. "Have been with in"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is the difference between the following two structures?

> Have you been back home **in** the last ten years?
>
> Have you been back home **for** the last ten years?

Could we also replace the present perfect with simple past as in the following:

> Did you go back home **in** the last ten years?
>
> Did you go back home **for** the last ten years? *(this one doesn't seem to be in accordance with the law of the books, but I don't see any problem with the structure assuming the person has visited once in the past 10 years at a particular time).*

Answer (score 5):

*in*, when used with a period of time, means "at some or any point in that interval", whereas *for* means "for the duration of the interval".

So your questions can be interpreted in this way:

> Have you been back home in the last ten years? (Have you been back home at any point in the last 10 years?)
>
> Have you been back home for the last ten years? (Have you spent the last 10 years at home?)

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is between "occurring at least once during the period" (Yes: I've visited home three times in the last ten years.) and "duration throughout the period" (No, I was living abroad for half of 2003 and all of 2008.)

The distinction remains the same in the past tense as in the present tense.